# How to downgrade cargo to an earlier version?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Have following version:

```
cargo 1.52.0 (69767412a 2021-04-21)
```

and I want to downgrade to 1.51. How is that achievable?

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use a specific version of the Rust toolchain, use `rustup install <TOOLCHAIN>` to download its components. You can verify it's available by using `rustup show`. Then you can set it as your default using `rustup default <TOOLCHAIN>`.

```sh
rustup install 1.51
rustup default 1.51
```

`cargo` should now use the `1.51` version unless otherwise [overridden](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustup/overrides.html).